# How to conditionally choose which column to SELECT based on WHERE clause, in a single query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

Here's the scenario. Let's say I have a table `Foo` with two columns, `bar` and `baz`. I want to check a condition on both `bar` and `baz`. This condition will only be true for one of the two columns. Whichever column it is true for, I want to select the other column.

I can write this as two separate queries, like this:

```
$one = Foo::select('bar as qux')->where('baz', $value);
$two = Foo::select('baz as qux')->where('bar', $value);
```

(For the sake of illustration, the condition in my example is checking if the column is equal to `$value`.)

After that, I suppose I could get the results of the two queries and merge them. However, I really want to use a `Paginator`, among other reasons for wanting it to be a single query.

I can select all of the relevant rows from the table using this:

```
$rows = Foo::where('baz', $value)->orWhere('bar', $value);
```

But then I do not know how to select `bar` or `baz` conditionally from there. It seems like the solution I seek would be some combination of the two methods above.

Is it possible to do this in a single query with Eloquent? I guess I can execute a raw query but I'd rather stay away from raw queries completely if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just use your orWhere query and just loop through the results checking for the right one?

```
$rows = Foo::where('baz', $value)->orWhere('bar', $value)->get();

foreach($rows as $row) {
   $qux = ($row->bar == $value) ? $row->baz : $row->bar;
   // do something with $qux
}
```

If you want to be more object centric, you could map the property qux to each row:

```
$rows = Foo::where('baz', $value)->orWhere('bar', $value)
    ->get()
    ->map(function($row) {
        $row->qux = ($row->bar == $value) ? $row->baz : $row->bar;
        return $row;
    });
```

Comment: My first response to you was to say: I don't want to `get()` the results right away because I want to Paginate them. But then it hit me that I can just Paginate the result of the `orWhere` and loop through that. Thanks, looks like this was a case of me overthinking it a lot!